# Unable to display new route (signin)in my website

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm  creating Amazon clone using react js.I'm completely new to reactjs.In My project  I stuck at routing of signIn and signUp part.I want to display sign in part but is not visible.I'm refering one youtube video where he just refreshing his home page and sign in part gets visible. but in my case it's not  showing any error but it's not loading sign in part.

**App.js**

```
    import './App.css';
    import Navbaar from './components/header/Navbaar';
    import Newnav from './components/newnavbaar/Newnav';
    import Maincomp from './components/home/Maincomp';
    import Footer from './components/footer/Footer';
    import Sign_in from './components/signup_signin/Sign_in';
    import SignUp from './components/signup_signin/SignUp';
    import {Routes ,Route} from "react-router-dom"


    function App() {
    return (
    <>
  
   <Navbaar/>
   <Newnav/>
   <Routes>
   <Route path = "/"  element={<Maincomp />} />
   <Route path = "/Sign_in"  element={<Sign_in/>} />
   <Route path = "/SignUp"  element={<SignUp/>} />
   </Routes>
   
   <Footer/>
   </>
   );
   }

   export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'; 
    import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

    ReactDOM.render(
    < BrowserRouter>

    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')

    );

    reportWebVitals();
```

**Signin.js**

```
    import React from 'react'
    import "./signup.css"

    const Sign_in = () => {
    return (
    <>
    <section>
    <div className="sign_container">


    <div className="sign_header">
    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Amazon_logo.svg/2560px- Amazon_logo.svg.png' alt='amazon logo' />
    </div>

    <div className="sign_form">
    <form>
    <h1> Sign-In</h1>
    <div className="form_data">
    <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email'/>
    </div>
    <div className="form_data">
    <label htmlFor=''>Password</label>
    <input type='password' name='password' id='password'/>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    </>
    )
    }

    export default Sign_in
```

I just want that Sign in Part should be display.